# How to restrict api gateway rest api to CloudFront hosted S3 website

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have hosted a S3 static site into CloudFront. That site using rest api deployed into api gateway. API gateway has not access control. 
I want to protect my api from being accessed by others. Only my static site can access it. I know I can use api key but that could expose by browser console which is not expected.
Is there other way to control my api access?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are couple of ways like CORS or less effective way such as restrict based on Referer header.

Comment: Are you trying to restrict access to logged in users only?

Comment: I don’t have login user. So, JWT auth not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue as well. It seems like using referer or CORS restrictions are the best way to go. However, in practice I haven't been able to make it work after trying both CORS and referer restrictions. API Gateway has automatic protection against malicious behavior like DDOS attacks according to their FAQs, but it is disheartening that I haven't found a specific solution for protecting my API gateway that is only used for my S3/Cloudfront static site.

Google Cloud allows you to use their API keys on the frontend for integrations with services like Google Maps. The way they protect those keys is through restricting the API keys to certain domains. Unfortunately, I haven't found similar functionality for AWS keys. As you know, the only way to throttle or put quotas on API gateway is through API keys, so it looks like this would be useless for a static site that can't expose those API keys publicly on the frontend.

It defeats the whole purpose of going completely serverless if I am unable to configure my serverless API Gateway the same way I could congfigure a normal backend EC2 server. For now, I've created billing alarms so I don't get surprised with a huge AWS bill if something goes wrong with my unprotected API gateway.